# Set string while series is a boolean value?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop, list-comprehension

I would like to set a string in Column C while values in Column B are >= 2 (yes if>= is True, no if >= is False). The output should be as follows:

```
    A B   C 
1   A 2 'yes'
2   B 3 'yes'
3   C 4 'yes'
4   D 5 'yes'
5   A 6 'yes'
6   B 7 'yes'
7   C 0 'no'
8   D 1 'no'
9   A 2 'yes'
10  B 3 'yes' 
11  C 4 'yes' 
12  D 0 'no'
```

So far I have tried to implement nested loops, which are far too slow:

```
i= 0
for row in range(0, len(df)-1):
    if df['B'][i] >= 2:
        if df['B'][i] >= 2:
            df['C'][i] = 'yes'
        elif df['B'][i] >= 2:
            df['C'][i] = 'yes'
```

Comment: Your question and your for loop are saying two different things. You didn't mention in your question that the row after the one you are checking must also be greater than or equal to 2.

Comment: You are correct - my apologies. This was from a prior attempt, so I have edited the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.where

```
df['C'] = np.where(df.B>=2, 'yes', 'no')

    A   B   C
1   A   2   yes
2   B   3   yes
3   C   4   yes
4   D   5   yes
5   A   6   yes
6   B   7   yes
7   C   0   no
8   D   1   no
9   A   2   yes
10  B   3   yes
11  C   4   yes
12  D   0   no
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
df['C'] = 'no'
df['C'][df['B'] >= 2] = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done simply by creating a Boolean valued column 'C' as per your condition:

```
df['C'] = df['B'] >= 2
```

But if you only want 'Yes' and 'No' values then you can convert your Boolean valued column to string and apply replace function.

```
df['C'] = df['C'].astype(str)
df['C'].replace('False','No', inplace=True)
df['C'].replace('True','Yes', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can by done by using "apply" on column B along with a lambda function and a ternary "if":

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'B': [1, 2, 3]})
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda r: "yes" if r >= 2 else "no")
```

"apply" applied to a column of a DataFrame will let you apply a function to each value in the dataframe. So we test if each value is >= 2, and if so, return "yes", otherwise "no".